# C - Implementing fetchAndSet with GCC atomic builtins -- is there a better way?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic

I'm looking for a simple, efficient way to implement a simple fetchAndSet with the GCC atomic builtins. The closest thing I see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) is the `__sync_lock_test_and_set` builtin, but that doesn't issue a full memory barrier like the others do, and all of the other functions either do operations (add, sub, xor, etc.) or are conditional (the compare and swap functions). These won't work because I'm trying to manipulate a variable holding arbitrary pointer data.

The best I could come up with was something like this:

```
type *fetchAndSet(type **loc, type *newvar) {
  while (1) {
    type *oldvar = __sync_fetch_and_add(loc, 0);
    if (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(loc, oldvar, newvar)) return oldvar;
  }
}
```

... in other words, I'm atomically fetching the value at the memory location, then breaking out of the loop as soon as I successfully replace that old value with the new value.  I'm not really satisfied with this solution since it's not a single atomic operation, and there's a pretty heavy risk of starvation if two or more threads are vying for the same memory location.  So, my question: is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the builtins in gcc 4.6 (per your link), you could change your sample code to (ideally) only issue one sync instruction, as you don't need to fetch the value with a sync.

```
type *fetchAndSet(type **loc, type *newvar) {
  while (1) {
    type *oldvar = *loc;
    if (__sync_val_compare_and_swap(loc, oldvar, newvar) == oldvar) return oldvar;
  }
}
```

A second option would be to add the __sync_synchronize() ahead of the call to __sync_lock_test_and_set(), so that there is a full barrier present.

Moving beyond the builtins in gcc 4.6, I refer you to R's answer.

Comment: Thanks, the two of you helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of GCC have new atomic builtins designed for implementing C11 `stdatomic.h`. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html. Unfortunately I'm not sure what the first version to add these was, so depending on your compatibility needs they might not be suitable (but you could use an ugly fallback like you're already doing). You could also include inline asm for the particular cpus you care about; on x86 it's trivial:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ( "xchg %0,%1" : "+r"(val), "+m"(*ptr) : : "memory" );
```

In the long term, you should be using `stdatomic.h`, but unfortunately we're not there yet...